# ubuntu integrated graphics suspend + hybrid graphics

Tags: 12.10, suspend, hybrid-graphics

My laptop uses a hybrid graphics hardware.

Using the vgaswitcheroo I am able to power off either card and switch between them correctly.

The issue is that the system wakes up/resumes from suspend correctly only when using the discrete graphics, or atleast the discrete graphics must be powered on even if the display is connected to the onboard intel card.

Has anyone faced this issues? Is there any workaround?

I only want to use the integrated card and not the discrete amd card.

System Info
Intel HD 3000
ATI mobility radeon HD 7600M
Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Updating the BIOS fixed it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try. Which system are you using? Mine is the HP envy 4 ultrabook. If its the same or similar then I have some other questions that I would really like to ask.